# Is it possible to override default_scope in rails_admin?

Tags: rails-admin

For example, I have:

```
class Answer
  include Mongoid::Document
  default_scope where(status: "active")
end
```

However, when I have this class then none of my hidden answers show up in rails_admin.  Any recommendations on this?

Comment: this answer could help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069425/how-do-i-show-unscoped-models-in-rails-admin

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
list
  scopes [:unscoped, :nil, :scope1]
```