# How do I show unscoped models in Rails Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, rails-admin

I needed this myself, so here it is QA-style:

By default, [Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) shows a model's default_scope. How do I get it to show every model completely unscoped?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Approach 1**

If you only need to list the records you can use the [scopes](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List) method to control which records are returned. The first array element is the default, so if you add the following to your initialiser:

```
list do
  scopes [:unscoped]
end
```

you will see all records.

**Approach 2**

If you want to do more than list models you can create a dummy rails admin model. For example, assuming you have a Post model with a boolean archived flag:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { archived: false }
end
```

You can create a dummy model to use in rails_admin like so (in app/models/rails_admin)

```
class RailsAdmin::Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "posts"
end
```

You then configure rails_admin to use RailsAdmin::Post and all of the Posts will be unscoped.

Answer (score 5):

Add this monkey patch to your rails admin initializer:

```
### Monkey pactch for unscoped records in admin panel
require 'rails_admin/main_controller'
module RailsAdmin
  class MainController
    alias_method :old_get_collection, :get_collection
    alias_method :old_get_object, :get_object

    def get_collection(model_config, scope, pagination)
      old_get_collection(model_config, model_config.abstract_model.model.unscoped, pagination)
    end

    def get_object
      raise RailsAdmin::ObjectNotFound unless (object = @abstract_model.model.unscoped.find(params[:id]))
      @object = RailsAdmin::Adapters::ActiveRecord::AbstractObject.new(object)
    end
  end
end
```

Taken from https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/353.

Answer (score 4):

I have a solution similar to Charles' above but that monkey patches the model layer rather than the controller layer. This might be a bit more stable across Rails Admin releases, but is ActiveRecord-specific and doesn't affect Mongoid, though the principle would be easily applied to the other adapter.

Again, put it in the rails admin initializer.

```
#
# Monkey patch to remove default_scope
#
require 'rails_admin/adapters/active_record'
module RailsAdmin::Adapters::ActiveRecord
  def get(id)
    return unless object = scoped.where(primary_key => id).first
    AbstractObject.new object
  end
  def scoped
    model.unscoped
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm making a pull request for the rails_admin project so hopefully we won't have to monkey patch any more.

Comment: If you're getting an error claiming that `object` is not defined, like I was, I found adding this line right below `def get(id)` solved my problem: `object = model.with_deleted.find(id)` (in my case, I'm using `paranoia`, so my "un-scoped scope" is `with_deleted`)

Answer (score 0):

My monkey patch, for Mongoid:

```
module RailsAdminFindUnscopedPatch
  def get(id)
    RailsAdmin::Adapters::Mongoid::AbstractObject.new(model.unscoped.find(id))
  rescue
    super
  end
end

RailsAdmin::Adapters::Mongoid.prepend(RailsAdminFindUnscopedPatch)
```

I'm reusing original rescue clause (`super` call).