# Manage soft deleted records(paranoia) in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

In my rails 4 app I'm using paranoia to soft delete users and rails_admin for admin interface.

Currently in rails_admin after deleting a record it doesn't show deleted records. I want to see all records in rails_admin where deleted records are marked differently and create a custom action to restore deleted records.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069425/how-do-i-show-unscoped-models-in-rails-admin

Answer (score 3):

You now have deleted scope on your model.  Add this to rails_admin config to view your deleted records:

```
list do
  scopes    [nil, 'deleted']
```