# Rails_admin and paranoia

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin, ruby-paranoia

Is there a way to manage the 'soft-deleted' records that [paranoia](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia) produces when I delete something?  What I mean is that any records I delete in [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) or rails console aren't actually deleted, instead paranoia marks them with a `deleted_at` timestamp, which takes them out of view scope.

I'd like to be able to see these deleted records for auditing, potential recovery, or to really delete them for good.

I have a basic install of rails_admin and paranoia, nothing special.

Also, [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290670/manage-soft-deleted-recordsparanoia-in-rails-admin) was no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list do
  scopes [nil, :only_deleted]
end
```

`nil`, simply means no scope, or original scope I should say. See more details on [rails_admin's Wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List)

Remember paranoia, simply adds a default scope, so records are hidden by default, but `unscoped` or one of the provided scopes should show them.

Comment: You're suggesting putting that scope in my User model?

Comment: No, paranoia, already put it for you. this is code that sould go in, for example, your _users.rb_. where you have `ActiveAdmin.register User do ...`

Comment: I guess we have a disconnect, I'm using rails_admin, not active_admin

Comment: I'm really sorry, it's me the one that is distracted. See updated answer.

Comment: Awesome!  Now I just need to figure out the custom action to restore or really_delete users

Comment: @Godzilla74 the newly selected answer, doesn't answer the original question, but the follow up we discussed in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

To restore soft deleted users you need to create RailsAdmin custom action.  Here is a relevant post [RailsAdmin custom action to restore soft deleted records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758736/railsadmin-custom-action-to-restore-soft-deleted-records).