# RailsAdmin custom action to restore soft deleted records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, rails-admin, acts-as-paranoid

I am using Rails 4.1.14 with rails_admin 0.8.1, mongoid 5.0 and [mongoid_paranoia](https://github.com/simi/mongoid_paranoia).  I created [RailsAdmin custom action](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-action) to restore soft deleted Users.

```
class Restore
  ...
  register_instance_option :controller do
    Proc.new do
      object.restore
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

But I keep getting

```
User with id '5695997df5740c17b0000002' could not be found
```

From my develoment.log

```
Started GET "/admin/user/5695997df5740c17b0000002/restore" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-12 16:35:04 -0800
Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#restore as HTML
  Parameters: {"model_name"=>"user", "id"=>"5695997df5740c17b0000002"}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | rails425_dev.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"deleted_at"=>nil, "_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('56956c76f5740c1d68000000')}, "limit"=>-1}
```

The problem is per default_scope query filters out records where deleted_at is not nil.  Any suggestions on how to override it?

Comment: How did you manage to restore records in rails_admin with paranoia? I've added with_deleted and only_deleted scopes and I'm seeing them but not able to restore or permanently destroy them. Even added custom action to restore it but it says record not found.

Comment: To answer @StarWars question from almost 2 years ago, see Dave Burt's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069425/how-do-i-show-unscoped-models-in-rails-admin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'll have to list this as an answer because I do not have the reputation to comment.

I believe your question may be answered here:
[How do I show unscoped models in Rails Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069425/how-do-i-show-unscoped-models-in-rails-admin)

The way I'd approach it is to create a scope that does satisfy my requirements for RailsAdmin and use that scope instead; that said, in general I try to avoid `default_scope` whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks.  Per link provided I had to modify get_object in MainController.      def get_object
      fail(RailsAdmin::ObjectNotFound) unless ( @object = @abstract_model.model.unscoped.find(params[:id]) )
    end